# Why did Apache Archiva never "go anywhere"?

Tags: archiva, artifact

It seems like a free, artifact storage application with a nice GUI for jars, wars, rpms, etc. is really needed given that SVN is a bit old and Artifactory and Nexus (can be) are quite expensive.  So I am confused as to why Apache Archiva never really went anywhere?  I know the main engineer just released a new version just before the time of this writing and I am grateful for his time and effort.  Nonetheless, it seems like this product never really caught on for build and devops teams even though it should have...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's hard without more contributors :-(

Please note the project is now using git https://github.com/apache/archiva

I'm who you call the main engineer. I was paid few years ago to work on this project but now I do it during my spare time (and I have limited spare time :-( ).

Why not contributing/helping? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Olamy.  I've emailed you : )

Comment: @olamy: can you look into this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478724/how-to-add-a-repository-to-archiva