# How to add a repository to archiva?

Tags: archiva

I have installed archiva on a server and when I access the dashboard, I can't find option to make new project or upload repositories.
Any idea on how to do it?

[image: Dashboard Screenshot]

**EDIT::**
Now it looks something like this: 
[image]

Do we have documentation on how to create repository and add artifacts?

Comment: Weird. Using version 2.2.1, just after setting up the admin account I was redirected to the management dashboard. Try to install the newest version.

Comment: @cesarse: I installed 2.2.1 yet I am getting the same dashboard! How do I create a new repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably had a corrupt admin setup due to which you were not able to see the admin page. Recover your admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: Good documentation here!!
http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/adminguide/repositories.html

Link to video tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4DoLCfYR-A